# Word for something whose name is not revealed in a novel?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing as essay and I wish to introduce the 'father' character, by using an adjective to describe the nature of his role/name. In this book, the father is always referred to as just 'father', and his name is never revealed.

Ie: "In the novel, the ________ father..."

Is there a word for this?

Comment: You might want to complete the question, and include a sample sentence for where the word might be used.

Comment: How about just "the father" or "[character name]'s father"?

Answer (score 6):

[Unnamed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unnamed) might be the word you're looking for.

Example: [10 Compelling Unnamed Protagonists in Literature](https://www.flavorwire.com/442853/10-compelling-unnamed-protagonists-in-literature)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use "***anonymous***" -

## Anonymous

> **2**: not named or identified

([Meriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anonymous))

> "*In the novel, the **anonymous** father...*"

Answer (score 0):

**Eponymous**

The ‘*eponymous father*’ or ‘*the one who is known by that name*’ ie - ‘father’.

Or you could simply say ‘*the character known as ‘father*’...

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eponymous

Comment: This is definitely incorrect usage.

Comment: Incorrect usage of what? @eyeballfrog